# Connection refused between Node and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, symfony

Getting this error when I try to connect my Node to my MongoDB

(But pretty new with both mongo and node so I might be doing something wrong...)

> > MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
> >         at Socket.err (/var/www/rzp/api/web/server_node/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:287:16)
> >         at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
> >         at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
> >         at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
> >         at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
> >         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

Symfony Side

config.yml

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: "%mongodb_server%"
            options: {}
    default_database: rzp_users
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
```

parameters.yml

```
mongodb_server: "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
```

Node server.js

```
// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';


MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err,client){
```

I think my Mongo configuration for Symfony is fine (not sure)

```
php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AppRefactoredBundle

Generating documents for "AppRefactoredBundle"
generating AppRefactoredBundle\Document\UserConnected
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try to change localhost to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @izk Just did, same issue

Comment: Issue updated with the new values

Comment: do you start the mongo server ?

Comment: @ASSILITaher I made sudo service mongod start so I guess it is launched.